# How can I change keyboard shortcuts in Chrome OS?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I'm using a Chromebook as a development system (sort of), and part of that means I'm afflicted with [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) key bindings, which in some cases conflict with existing key bindings, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> for changing input languages. I'd love to either disable this or change the key binding, by whatever means possible. I have Linux installed via [Crouton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crouton_(computing)) if that helps. Is this a known way to do this?

I don't really want to universally change the behavior of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, for instance, which seems to be an option in *Settings*.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this.  Now Debian can basically be installed on Chrome OS so the preferences in terminal may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to my question, but for my purposes (using terminal apps), it works! The workaround for my particular case was to install the Chrome App [Crosh Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crosh-window/nhbmpbdladcchdhkemlojfjdknjadhmh?hl=en-US), which will cause `crosh` to be launched in a special "non-browser" window where the usual key-bindings are not intercepted.

Comment: The official secure shell app can also launch Crosh window but you'd want to put the Chromebook into developer mode and install Chromebrew or Crouton to get way more functionality.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-app/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo